# Is possibly for groups to stack horizontally instead of vertically?

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm putting together a report based on a multiple choice field of 20 possible entries. I'm trying to show numbers across months. So I have a formula to parse each individual entry from responses and created 20 of them for each possible answer.

Here's an example:

```
if isnull({return:reason}) then 0
else if instr({return:reason}, "Paint Chipping")>0 then 1 
else 0
```

Each incident is recorded with the date it was reported. I made the date a group and had the group set for each month.

So my results look like this:

```
Month     Paint Chipping        Leak         Broken
May 2018      2                  4              5
June 2018     1                  4               0
July 2018      0                 1               2
```

Here I used 3 examples but there are twenty categories (most with longer names) and even in the landscape orientation it is too much.

Is there a way to get groups (and really the whole report) to stack horizontally instead of vertically so I can get this instead

```
Reason            May 2018    June 2018    July 2018 
Paint Chipping        2            1           0
Leak                  4            4           1
Broken                5            0           2
```

One of the parameters is a date range and it won't go beyond a year's time so I won't run into the same as with the other orientation.

I did consider formatting the fields so that the table could be read in a portrait orientation while the report still was in landscape orientation but that is a pain for our users plus the report viewer we use with our software does not allow you to change orientation.

Is this possible or if there is another way to get what I'm after let me know.

Comment: Have you tried using 'cross table'?

Comment: As mentioned above - Cross Tabs would be your best bet.

Comment: I would do crosstab but I have 20 different fields to put into rows all of which return the null value. The crosstab that is produced is a hot mess.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the data as below, a crosstab would be very easy to solve this with.

https://youtu.be/23zBMWLxueA?t=340

```
Month      Reason           Value
May 2018   Paint shipping   2
June 2018  Paint shipping   1
May 2018   Leak             4
June 2018  Leak             4
July 2018  Leak             1
May 2018   Broken           5
June 2018  Broken           0
July 2018  Broken           2
```